# Visual Studio 2008 - How to upgrade from RTM to SP?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, upgrade

I have on machine (Windows XP) this installed :

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
>
> Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM

And I need to upgrade to this version :

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
>
> Version 9.0.30729.1 SP

What should I install?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest service pack for Visual Studio 2008 is SP1:

> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986

And there is a Roll-up pack to connect to the latest version of Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Online. This also contain minor fixes for other Visual Studio 2008 features and is highly recommended to be installed, even if you're not using TFS.

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2673642/en-us